# How hard the discrete logarithm Problem modulo P is

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity, discrete-logarithms

I actually have two questions related to how hard the discrete logarithm problem is. In the two questions, I will use the following notation for the DLP:

- $g^x\equiv h \pmod{p}$, where $p$ is a prime, and $g$ is of order $n$

The first question: I'm reading a book about cryptography, in which the author, trying to demonstrate how hard it is to solve the DLP, states "we might try choosing random values of $x$, compute $g^x$, and
check if $g^x = h$. Using the fast exponentiation method,
it takes a small multiple of $\log_2(x)$ modular multiplications to compute $g^x$". So, when I tried to find bounds for this "small multiple" of $\log_2(x)$ mathematically, I found that it can be at most $2$ and can be as low as $1$. Is this what he meant or is there something that I am missing? NOTE: in the book, he uses the fast powering algorithm to do exponentiation.
The second question: In the same book, the author continues by saying "If $n$ and $x$ are $k$-bit numbers, that is, they are each approximately $2^k$, then this
trial-and-error approach requires about $k·2^k$ multiplications". If the author means that this is the number of multiplication that is needed to brute force the DLP over all exponents $1\le x\le n$, then it won't be true because for example small exponets will take much less multiplications than bigger exponents, So obviously, the number of multiplications will be less than that. But, I don't think he meant that because he says that $x $ and n are $k$-bit numbers. Does this mean that $x$ is fixed, and if it is fixed how is this different from the situations I described in the first question.

Comment: The number of multiplications won't be that much less. Half of the exponents have the same number of bits as the largest exponent, so all of them will take $k$ multiplications; that already yields $k\cdot 2^{k-1}$ which is only off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @GregMartin can you explain how did you get that answer, please?

Comment: Try small examples ? $$2^x\equiv 48\pmod {53}$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yeah, I just got it, but what about my answer to the first question?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee and also what did he mean by x is k-bit number, when it actually runs from 1 bit to k-bits

Comment: x was 21 in my example.

Comment: what does this have to do with my question

Comment: It's an example of a discrete log modulo a prime. Most people on this site don't take to no effort questions. Asymptically all small multiples of log n are log n complexity